# OS X slows down every day at midnight?

Tags: macos, performance

In about 50 minutes from now (it's 11:06 PM) my machine will slow down. It does this every night at the exact same time.

Is OSX indexing or what is going on and what can I do about it?

Comment: Open up Activity Monitor and sort all processes by CPU usage. When your computer slows down, find the offending process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your computer is running the `periodic` daily scripts. These just clean up temporary files, caches, and do other daily maintenance. You can read more about it on Apple's site [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2319).

Comment: Never knew about that before... thanks for providing that info!

Comment: Nope, this isn't it; the daily (and weekly) periodic scripts don't run at midnight, they run at 3:15 am, and the monthly one runs at 5:30 am (see the Additional Information section of the linked article, or the actual launchd files in /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.periodic-*.plist).

Comment: Gordon is correct, the dailies run at 03:15 each day. I know this because I set up a script that would mount my Ext. FW HDD when daily script ran, and the HDD always mounted at 03:15.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make them happen when you're free to take the performance hit, type sudo periodic daily into the terminal.